# Change URL after submiting form but while rendering view in Grails

Tags: url, search, grails, mapping, render

Hello there Grails community wherever you are! I'm facing a cool problem... or idea even. And I need some help.

What I try to do is this:

1. Submit search form with a phrase. Let's say 'pants'.
2. Value is submitted to /search/list (searchController => list method)
3. Invoke finder returning a list of pants in diffrent shops (a, b, c) and different categories (aaa, bbb, ccc) as a result.
4. By default /search/list is the rendered URL where I can show the list, but instead of...

myapp.com/search/list?search=pants

I would like to show the URL in the browser like this

myapp.com/a-b-c/aaa-bbb-ccc?search=pants

without redirecting using urlMapping and thus invoking the list method again.

Of course the same typed URL without submitting my search form would give the same list of pants, only I would have more criteria at the start (shops = [a, b, c], categories = [aaa, bbb, ccc] and searched phrase "pants").

I hope I sound clear enough. Thinking out of the box appreciated.

PS. Maybe you know some solutions in Ruby, Java or PHP to deal with such situation?

Answer (score 0):

well, you could use urlmappings for this.

```
"/$shops/$categories/$search" {
 controller = "search"
 action = "list"
 constraints {
      shops(matches:/\w-\w-\w/)
      categories(matches:/\w+-\w+-\w+/)
 }
}
```

If my regex matching is correct then this
would match myapp.com/a-b-c/aaa-bbb-ccc?search=pants and
would match myapp.com/a-b-c/aaa-bbb-ccc/pants

I think you can also add some preprocessing in the urlmappings, for example you could do

```
"/$shops/$categories/$search" {
  ...
  shops = shops.split('-')
  categories = categories.split('-') 
  ...
}
```

However, im not 100% sure on this.

Comment: Point is that while I submit search form the only variable I have is searched phrase 'pants' in params. Next thing is finiding List<Product> containing Shops and Categories. Having this I can prepare two Strings using split You mention, ie. 'a-b-c' for Shops and 'aaa-bbb-ccc' for Categories. And now is the tricky part, cause I would like to show url which is based on variables I just got from invoking list method in search controller, without redirecting and thus searching all over again having extra params from Url (Shops => ['a', 'b', 'c'], Categorie => ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']. PS. I try chain

Comment: why dont you create a simple intermediary, which redirects to the real search engine. eg. you have an action search that doesnt do any thing else than redirect to "/$shops/$categories/$search" with the correct parameters. Don't overengineer.